# Fortran project compiles without error, execution yields "This app can't run on your PC"

Tags: fortran, codeblocks, gfortran

I attempted to compile TALYS-1.8 (a free nuclear physics code) on a Win10-64 PC using Code:Blocks and gfortran, and no errors were observed during building.  However, the resulting executable (talys.exe) fails to run from the Windows console (with administrator privileges), prompting the dreaded "This app can't run on your PC" popup and the "access is denied" message in the command terminal.

For those interested in trying this, the TALYS-1.8 source may be downloaded from the developer's website at http://www.talys.eu/download-talys/

The only source file I modified was machine.f, setting nulldev='NUL    ' (line 27) and home='c:/' (line 38) in accordance with the Windows OS.

It may well be obvious at this point, but I don't do much programming and am at the limits of my knowledge in attempting to diagnose the issue here.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: gfortran installer is this one:  users.humboldt.edu/finneyb/gfortran-windows-20140629.exe

Windows SmartScreen has been disabled with no change in outcome.

Compiler flags I turned on are -g -fcheck=all -W -Wextra -cpp  I do not think the preprocessor flag is needed for this project.

Comment: Have you tried disabling [SmartScreen](https://www.howtogeek.com/75356/how-to-turn-off-or-disable-the-smartscreen-filter-in-windows-8/)?

Comment: Wee nees to soo the gfortran veersion and where did you get it and also allcompiler flags you used.

Comment: I have disabled SmartScreen, and still have the problem.

Comment: I use gfortran from the following link: http://users.humboldt.edu/finneyb/gfortran-windows-20140629.exe

Compiler flags: -g -fcheck=all -W -Wextra -cpp

Comment: Where did you find this link? What kind of version that is? Did they say that it is compatible with your Windows version?

Comment: @VladimirF The gfortran link above is from https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries.  I don't see any problem with compatibility with Win10-64.  In fact, I can compile the little "hello world" program in Code::Blocks and that runs just fine.  

C:\gfortran\bin>gfortran.exe -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: [redacted for length]
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.10.0 20140629 (experimental) [trunk revision 212119] (GCC)